# A way to save pixels drawn on canvas after paint call in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm coming from a web background and I think when you're drawing an animation on a canvas there, you have to clear the canvas after every tick (otherwise you'd be drawing over your previous frame):

```js
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

In Flutter I think the canvas is cleared for you every time you call `paint` inside the `CustomPainter`. That's great but is there anyway to keep that other functionality of just drawing over what you've previously drawn?

For context, I'm animating random walkers and I don't really want to keep track of all the previous points they've visited.

I've tried `context.save()` and `context.restore()` but that seems related to transforms and not pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be late ...

Import 'rendering' and 'ui' packages with:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
```

Add the next function:

```
Future<ui.Image> canvasToImage(CustomPainter painter, Size size) async 
{
  ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
  Canvas canvas = Canvas(recorder);
  if (painter != null) painter.paint(canvas, size);
  return await recorder.endRecording().toImage(size.width.floor(), size.height.floor());
}
```

Use the previous function, to draw into an image, for example an image named 'previousCanvas'.

At the 'paint' function of your 'CustomPainter' draw the image if available:

```
if (previousCanvas != null) {
    canvas.drawImage(previousCanvas, Offset(0, 0), Paint());
}
```

It is 'async' and it is 'slow' but it works. I don't know if there is a better way of doing it.

Also, you can modify the function to draw into the 'canvas' object instead of calling a painter with '.paint'

Comment: This seems reasonable. I had actually come across using a Recorder for something similar while writing this question but never really tested it. Thanks